# Conditional template tag for buddypress pages

Tags: templates, buddypress, template-tags

I'm trying to assign a special template only to buddypress pages (activity, members, profile...). All other posts / pages use a different template. Problem is: I just can't find a good way to tell if a page is "rendered" by buddypress or by the wp "core". I've looked in the bp codex and found the template tag bp_is_member() and others, but none for an overall approach. Are there hooks that I could use or other template tags that I didn't find?

I'm not looking for a customization of the sidebar only, so conditional widget plugins won't do the job.

Any help is appreciated
Heiner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bp_current_component()` does not necessarily return a boolean - it returns `false` if not in a BP component, but will return the name of the component otherwise, as a string.

Internally, BP uses the function `bp_is_blog_page()` to do what you're asking - if it returns true, it's not a BP page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the solution to my problem. Buddypress offers a simple function that returns a boolean value:

```
bp_current_component();
```

Now all I have to do is call that function and include it in an if else statement.

Thanks to ZaMoose who has found this easy solution http://xrl.us/bmxm8e

Hope this helps some else also.